# connect() to unix:///tmp/uwsgi_dev.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

Tags: cron, nginx, django, uwsgi

I tried to run django application using uwsgi+nginx and the cronjob command is,
`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/lockrun --lockfile /path/to/lock_file -- uwsgi --close-on-exec -s /path/to/socket_file --chdir /path/to/project/folder/ --pp .. -w project_name.wsgi -C666 -p 32 -H /path/to/virtualenv/ 1>> /path/to/success_log 2>> /path/to/error_log`
but I receive the error in nginx error log file as,
**019/11/20 06:45:21 [crit] 1986#1986: *2 connect() to unix:///path/to/socket_file failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /auth/status/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///path/to/socket_file:", host: "xx.xxx.xx.xxx", referrer: "http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/"**
the path for the socket_file in nginx configuration file and in cronjob command is same, can any one have idea where I'm making the mistake???

Comment: What does Your nginx config for this look like? Do the usgwi log files say anything? Is the socket there? Is the usgwi starting at all from Your crontab? (And why at all crontab?)

Comment: actually this method is used by my predecessor, and I'm not that good with server all those things, so I'm trying these method to get the solution, <br/>server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;location ~ ^/(api|pd|voice_service|auth|admin)/ {
                #development
                #proxy_pass  http://0.0.0.0:8889;
                client_max_body_size 10M;
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass   unix:///tmp/uwsgi_dev.sock;
                uwsgi_read_timeout 300s;
        }

Comment: log file is no created, socket also not created the above error is shown in nginx error log...

Answer (score 0):

Your uwsgi server is not starting if the socket is not there and no logfiles created.
As /path/to/error_log is not there I would assume cron is not working on that machine or a permission problem (owner of crontab cannot write the logfiles at least).

Anyway normally You would not start a server like that. Ok it would restart it within a minute if it is unstable or such, but such problem should be solved other way. Better make a systemd unit where You can configure the service to be restarted automatically as soon as it breaks away, no need for lockrun or such.

Try to start the server with the user (crontab owner) with

```
uwsgi --close-on-exec -s /path/to/socket_file --chdir /path/to/project/folder/ --pp .. -w project_name.wsgi -C666 -p 32 -H /path/to/virtualenv/
```

on the shell an see what You get. Alternatively check Your mailbox (`mail`), possibly You will find some error messages from cron there...

Comment: owner have the permission to create crontab, but not know about the log files, if we run `uwsgi --ini ini_file` the server will work, and if I create **rc.local** file and insert the line `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data --daemonize /var/log/uwsgi-emperor.log` it's not starting the server (it found from the document)

Comment: we need to specify the exact location where the uwsgi installed, then the server will start...thanks for spending your valuable time....

Comment: What happens if You use exact same command line You have in cron - with and without the leading `/usr/local/bin/lockrun --lockfile /path/to/lock_file --`? Is there a mail in Your mailbox from cron daemon?

Comment: both works fine, but I'm facing a new problem if I use the **rc.local** file it's not working (the first comment). can you suggest any solution for that....

Comment: So remaining issue for crontab may be the environment then or that Cron does not run at all. So You really should check mails and/or systemlog for any traces of front. For rc.local the same. Did You try with same command line pasted in the shell? There might also be a different environment. Also if You are an a modern Linux rc.local is not good and possibly not working as expected, a systemd unit or such should be created instead. Which kind and version of Linux You have there?

Comment: My server is too slow and unable to connect, I don't know why? once I connected mysql server was down, but some how I managed to up the mysql server, but when I run the application in cronjob again it become too slow and unable to connect through ssh and in browser also...What might be the issue??

Comment: low on memory? (Swapping..) - This could also explain the app not starting..

Comment: **upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream** this is what I'm getting in my nginx error log...

Comment: Yes I told You. Check Your memory usage if programs don't start and get extremely slow. Or Your CPU usage. Or Your as app is broken and does not respond, possibly bringing down MySQL. Or MySQL database is broken (unlikely) and causes Your app hanging

Comment: I tried `df -h` command to  check the memeory but it shows enough memory usage and there is half of the memory is still avail....

Comment: df is not memory but storage/disk. Use free to check memory/ram/swap or better tools like atop or top to see what's going on.